# Analysis based on GC caused suspension time

Tags: performance, testing, dynatrace

How to anlayze the performance of an application based on GC caused suspension time. If Dynatrace shows a red exclamation mark as warning for GC suspension time, what is the meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynatrace will usually flag your GC in red if you spend more than 15% of the execution time on garbage collections.
This is what must have happened to you.